# PHP: Return if statements into HTML element

Tags: javascript, php, html

How would you return a value of an if statement into a specific HTML element when using a combination of PHP and HTML in the same doc.

For example. With native JavaScript let's say I write this:

```
var myVariable = "This will get appended";
var div = document.querySelector('.mydiv');

if ( test != functionResult  ) {
div.innerHTML = myVariable;
}

<div class="mydiv"></div>
```

I'm still learning PHP, but from what I understand, you might do this to achieve the same thing:

```
$myVariable = "This will get appended";

if ( $test != $functionResult  ) {
    $div = $myVariable; 
}


<div><?php echo $div ?></div>
```

Is this the correct PHP syntax for this function?

Comment: Yeah why not ? Whats wrong with this

Comment: Did you try?  Does this work the way you want it to without any side-effects?  Seems like this is something that can easily be tested.

Comment: that appears to be valid PHP yes.

Comment: All PHP statements should be inside <?php  ?> tag, which is not the case of your example.
The last line could be 
**echo "<div>$div</div>";**

Answer (score 1):

This is what I interpreted as what you were looking for:

```
<div>
<? if($test!=$functionresult): ?>
    This will get appeneded
<? endif; ?>
</div>
```

Or if you don't want the div to show if it is false:

```
<? if($test!=$functionresult): ?>
    <div> This will be appended </div>
<? endif; ?>
```